# Style:Display and Visibility errors?

Tags: html, css, html-table, visibility

```
< table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">  
    < tr>
        < td>1< /td>  
        < td>1< /td>
        < td>1< /td>
        < td>1< /td>
        < td>1< /td>
    </tr>
    < tr style="display:block ">
        < td>2< /td>
        < td>2< /td>
        < td>2< /td>
        < td>2< /td>
        < td>2< /td>
    </ tr>
    < tr style="visibility:hidden ">
        < td>3< /td>
        < td>3< /td>
        < td>3< /td>
        < td>3< /td>
        < td>3< /td>
    < /tr>
    < tr style="visibility:hidden ">
        < td>4< /td>
        < td>4< /td>
        < td>4< /td>
        < td>4< /td>
        < td>4< /td>
    < /tr>
    < tr>
        < td>5< /td>
        < td>5< /td>
        < td>5< /td>
        < td>5< /td>
        < td>5< /td>
    < /tr>
    < tr>
        < td>6< /td>
    < /tr>
    < tr>
        < td>7< /td>
    < /tr>
< /table>
```

see the code I am using visibility and display for hidden or showing rows but both have errors

Visibility hide the row but do not removed space, like "display:none",
I can use "display" but it is not working properly with safari and Firefox.

Please give me solution for it.
My requirement is:-

Hide the row and also removed its space on all browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `display: block;` to `display: table-row;` for a start, then use `display: none;` instead of `visibility: hidden;`.

`display:block;` applies to div elements and similar, not table rows.

Answer (score 5):

`display: none` works fine to remove a table row in all browsers.

However what you have is `display: block`, which makes no sense. A ‘block’ element is like a `<div>`; you can't sensibly put one directly inside a `<table>`.

A table row that is not removed by `display: none` should have the display value `table-row`. However in IE only, before version 8, it is `display: block` instead. That means if you are switching between shown and removed with JavaScript, you would have to sniff the browser to choose whether to set `display: table-row` or `display: block` when re-showing the row.

In that case it is much easier to do it indirectly instead, by adding and removing `row.className= 'hidden'` and using a stylesheet rule to `.hidden { display: none; }`. This way requires no browser workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

don't use

```
style="display:block"
```

Also there are some basic missing in you code

such that dont use

```
< tr>
```

it should be

```
<tr>
```

Use colspan="" in your

Number of td in each row should be matched to work properly. if they don't match you have to adjust it properly using **colspan=""**

Following is work for me

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">  
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>  
        <td>1</td>  
        <td>1</td>  
        <td>1</td>  
        <td>1</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>  
        <td>2</td>  
        <td>2</td>  
        <td>2</td>  
        <td>2</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none">
        <td>3</td>  
        <td>3</td>  
        <td>3</td>  
        <td>3</td>  
        <td>3</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none ">
        <td>4</td>  
        <td>4</td>  
        <td>4</td>  
        <td>4</td>  
        <td>4</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>  
        <td>5</td>  
        <td>5</td>  
        <td>5</td>  
        <td>5</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">6</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">7</td>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit vague what you are after but `display:none` hides the rows and does not save space on all IE, FF and (as far as I know but I dont develop specifically for Safari) Safari.